# Make implicit rules with GCC: Redirecting *.o

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to get make to do the following with an implicit rule:

```
obj/lsabase.o : inc/lsabase.h lsabase.c
    cc -c lsabase.c && mv lsabase.o obj
```

I searched for ways to redirect the output of "cc -c .." with compiler options, but didn't find any [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_3.html#SEC17).

Also the implicit rule defined for compiling from source to object only lets you use $(CPPFLAGS) and $(CFLAGS).

Does anybody know how to trick make into using this (mv lsabase.o obj) in an implicit rule, so I can put all *.o files in a seperate directory?

Answer (score 2):

```
obj/lsabase.o : inc/lsabase.h lsabase.c
    cc -I"inc" -c lsabase.c -o obj/lsabase.o
```

Answer (score 0):

I would

- avoid doing the `mv` manually but rather telling gcc to put in the `obj` dir
- let gcc handle the dependencies (by creating `.d` files)

and here is what I usually do when all my .c files are in a subdir and I want to compile all of them in a parallel dir `obj` (that I can easily remove):

```
default: my_code

#add subdirs
DIRS := $(shell find src -type d)
#add include directives for subdirs
CFLAGS += $(DIRS:%=-I%)

#collect all c files
SRCS := $(shell find src/* -name \*.c)
OBJS := $(addprefix obj/, $(SRCS:.c=.o))
DEPS := $(addprefix obj/, $(SRCS:.c=.d))

# this generates a dependency file for every .c
obj/%.d: %.c
    @ mkdir -p "$(@D)" 
    @ echo "Checking dependencies for $<"
# create and modify dependecy file .d to take into account the location obj (sed magical)
    @ gcc $(CFLAGS) -MM $< 2>/dev/null | sed -e "s@\(^.*\)\.o:@obj/$(shell  dirname $<)/\1.d obj/$(shell  dirname $<)/\1.o:@" > $@  

#this compiles
obj/%.o : %.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#this creates the executable
my_code: $(OBJS)
    gcc $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) 

# this does the magic
-include $(DEPS)

clean:
    rm -rf obj
```

If you're new to Make, this might seem difficult, but it's really powerful once you get through.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is kinda blowing my head. Isn't there a simple way to do what @dasan did in the above comment, but with implicit rules and for every *.o file? I couldn't quite get you makefile running, I just get a bunch of errors, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

you can write the makefile rule this way:

```
obj/lsabase.o : lsabase.c inc/lsabase.h 
<tab>cc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -Iinc/.
```

where, in the actual makefile, the `<tab>` would be replaced with an actual tab character

Notice the *.c file is first in the list of dependencies, so can use the `$<` shortcut

You mentioned wanting to do this for all the object files..

```
obj/$.o : %.c inc/%.h 
<tab>cc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -Iinc/.
```

However, that may not be the most flexible.  For maximum flexibility, suggest adding a rule to generate and include dependency files named *.d.  Then using:

```
obj/$.o : %.c %.d 
<tab>cc $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -Iinc/.
```